# Align two pictures centrally side by side

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centerline{
\hspace*{-0cm}
\subfloat[2D MOT]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.05]{"2D-MOT".jpg}  }    %
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Differential pumping section]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.075]{"2D-MOTcoils".jpg}  } %
}
\caption{\textbf{Figure \ref*{fig:realMOT} }: The assembled 2D-MOT. Once cured, the glue turned orange. Showing single core copper wire for quad coils, blue offset coils}
\label{fig:realMOT}%
\end{figure}
```

which produces this result:

[image]

I would like the two figures to be aligned through their centre.

I have seen other answers and they all involve `subfigure`, `minipage` and other packages. 
 Is there a simple way to include a `vspace` *just* for one of the subfloat?

Comment: What about the subcaptions? Should they stay vertically aligned to the image or aligned with respect to each other (at the bottom of the larger image)?

Comment: Please also turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentcla,, the relevant packages and by replacing the images by appropriate example images (e. g. `example-image-9x16´ and `example-image`).

Comment: Unrelated to the alingment issue but what exactly is the reason for using `\caption{\textbf{Figure \ref*{fig:realMOT} }: `?

Comment: Whatever else you end up doing, please don't use `\centerline` in a LaTeX document. `\centerline` is a plain-TeX macro. Use `\centering` instead.

Comment: What does it mean to be a plain-TeX macro? What's the disadvanted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[2D MOT]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{"2D-MOT".jpg}  }    %
    \qquad
\subfloat[Differential pumping section]{\includegraphics[height=3cm,valign=c]{"2D-MOTcoils".jpg}}
\caption{The assembled 2D-MOT. Once cured, the glue turned orange. Showing single core copper wire for quad coils, blue offset coils}
\label{fig:realMOT}%
    \end{figure}
\noindent   or
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{"2D-MOT".jpg}}
    &
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=3cm,valign=c]{"2D-MOTcoils".jpg}} \\
\subfloat[2D MOT]{\rule{0.4\linewidth}{0pt}}
    &
\subfloat[Differential pumping section]{\rule{0.4\linewidth}{0pt}}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The assembled 2D-MOT. Once cured, the glue turned orange. Showing single core copper wire for quad coils, blue offset coils}
\label{fig:realMOT}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. I am using your second method, but the labels always come up as (c) and (d). Is there a way# to make then come out as (a) and (b)?